# How do I upgrade a DataStax Enterprise cluster to 6.8.25 with OpsCenter Lifecycle Manager?

Tags: upgrade, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

What are the steps (or all the commands) to upgrade (just the 6.8.25 fix, I have 6.18.16 version now) all nodes in cluster with LifeCycle Manager?

I've found this but it refers to 6.5 version of DSE:

https://docs.datastax.com/eol/en/opscenter/6.5/opsc/LCM/upgradeDSEjob.html

Answer (score 0):

The procedure for upgrading a [DataStax Enterprise (DSE)](https://www.datastax.com/products/datastax-enterprise) cluster, specifically for minor version upgrades, is documented in [Running an upgrade job for a DSE patch version](https://docs.datastax.com/en/opscenter/docs/6.8/LCM/upgradeDSEjob.html).

As always, if you need assistance then you should consider logging a ticket with [DataStax Support](https://support.datastax.com/) directly which is included in your DSE subscription. Cheers!